# Parse this to adjacency list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to parse this list to an adjacency list here the sample DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[classification](
    [sno] [float] NULL,
    [classification] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [classificationTitle] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (1, N'23-11 00 00', N'Site Products')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (2, N'23-11 11 00', N'Ground Anchorages')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (3, N'23-11 11 11', N'Retaining Stabilizing Ground Anchors')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (4, N'23-11 11 11 11', N'Retaining Stabilizing Ground Components')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (5, N'23-11 11 11 11 11', N'Stabilizing Ground Anchor Heads')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (6, N'23-11 11 11 11 13', N'Stabilizing Ground Tendons')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (7, N'23-11 11 11 13', N'Stabilizing Ground Grouted Anchors')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (8, N'23-11 11 11 15', N'Stabilizing Ground Plate Anchors')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (9, N'23-11 11 11 17', N'Stabilizing Ground Rock Bolts')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (10, N'23-11 11 11 19', N'Stabilizing Ground Rock Anchors')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (11, N'23-11 11 11 21', N'Stabilizing Ground Anchor Tiebacks')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (12, N'23-11 11 13', N'Earth Reinforcement Anchors')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (13, N'23-11 11 13 11', N'Earth Reinforcement Soil Nails')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (14, N'23-11 13 00', N'Ground Improvement Products')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (15, N'23-11 13 11', N'Soil Stabilization Products')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (16, N'23-11 13 11 11', N'Soil Stabilization Injectable Chemicals')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (17, N'23-11 13 11 13', N'Soil Stabilization Pressure Grouting')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (18, N'23-11 13 11 15', N'Ground Freezing Soil Stabilization')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (19, N'23-11 13 11 17', N'Soil Stabilization Fills')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (20, N'23-11 13 11 17 11', N'Soil Stabilization Fill Blocks')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (21, N'23-11 13 11 17 13', N'Soil Stabilization Compressible Fill')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (22, N'23-11 13 11 19', N'Other Soil Stabilizations')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (23, N'23-11 13 11 21', N'Piped Field Drainage')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (24, N'23-11 13 11 21 11', N'Field Drainage Land Drainage Pipes')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (25, N'23-11 13 11 23', N'Field Drainage Blocks')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (26, N'23-11 13 11 25', N'Field Drainage Geocomposite Drains')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (27, N'23-11 13 11 25 11', N'Field Drainage Geocomposite Edge Drains')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (28, N'23-11 13 11 25 13', N'Field Drainage Geocomposite In Place Wall Drains')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (29, N'23-11 13 11 27', N'Geotextile Subsurface Drainage Filtration')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (30, N'23-11 15 00', N'Sheeting and Revetments')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (31, N'23-11 15 11', N'Sheeting Geosynthetics')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (32, N'23-11 15 11 11', N'Sheeting Geotextiles')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (33, N'23-11 15 11 13', N'Sheeting Geogrids')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (34, N'23-11 15 11 15', N'Sheeting Geomembranes')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (35, N'23-11 15 11 17', N'Sheeting Geocomposites')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (36, N'23-11 15 11 19', N'Sheeting Mulch Control Netting')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (37, N'23-11 15 11 21', N'Sheeting Synthetic Erosion Controls')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (38, N'23-11 15 11 23', N'Sheeting Re vegetation Mats')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (39, N'23-11 15 11 25', N'Sheeting Turf Reinforcement Mats')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (40, N'23-11 15 13', N'Revetments')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (41, N'23-11 15 13 11', N'Revetment Soil Blankets')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (42, N'23-11 15 13 13', N'Pool Revetments')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (43, N'23-11 15 13 15', N'Trench Revetments')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (44, N'23-11 15 13 17', N'Revetment Rock Linings')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[classification] ([sno], [classification], [classificationTitle]) VALUES (45, N'23-11 15 13 19', N'Revetment Ripraps')
GO
```

and I am trying to get this output

```
+----------+---------+
| parentid | childid |
+----------+---------+
| NULL     |       1 |
| 1        |       2 |
| 2        |       3 |
| 3        |       4 |
| 4        |       5 |
| 4        |       6 |
| 3        |       7 |
| 3        |       8 |
| 3        |       9 |
| 3        |      10 |
| 3        |      11 |
| 1        |      12 |
| 12       |      13 |
+----------+---------+
```

So far I am have come up with this.

```
;with cte as (
select LEFT([classification], LEN([classification]) - 3)as immediateparent,
[classification],sno
FROM [classification]
)
select a.sno,cte.sno from [classification] a 
left join cte on cte.immediateparent =a.[classification]
```

But couldn't find upto end any help.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not clear to me: Why '23-11 00 00' is the parent of '23-11 11 00'?  In fact you are considering '23-11 11'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT  parent.sno parentid, child.sno childid
FROM    classification child
--get all the matches where parent.classification is a subset of child.classification
OUTER APPLY (
    --only consider the highest ranking result
    SELECT  TOP 1 *
    FROM    classification parent
    --ignore the 00 entries - these appear to represent null values
    WHERE   CHARINDEX(REPLACE(parent.classification, ' 00', ''), child.classification) > 0
    --don't consider equivalent records as a match
    AND parent.sno <> child.sno
    --where the rank is based on the length of the match (assume the longest match is the adjacent node
    ORDER BY LEN(REPLACE(parent.classification, ' 00', '')) DESC
) parent
--based on the results displayed in the question
WHERE   child.sno BETWEEN 1 AND 13
--based on the ordering displayed in the question
ORDER BY child.sno, parent.sno
```

I'm making the assumption that 00 values only appear at the end of a classification and that they can be ignored (i.e. they are placeholders for null, or something along those lines). An explanation of how the query works is in the comments of the code. This will work whether or not the graph entries in classification are in order by sno.

Comment: Also, if you decide that you'd rather list the parent of 1 as 1, then delete the AND line and change the internal ORDER BY to: ORDER BY CASE WHEN parent.sno = child.sno THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, LEN(REPLACE(parent.classification, ' 00', '')) DESC

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the desired result, but maybe a CROSS APPLY can solve your question.

> ```
> SELECT c1.sno, c1.classification, c2.nextClass, c2.nextSno
> FROM   Classification c1
> CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 classification nextClass, sno nextSno
>              FROM   classification
>              WHERE  classification > c1.classification
>              ORDER BY classification) c2
> ORDER BY classification;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> sno | classification    | nextClass         | nextSno
> --: | :---------------- | :---------------- | ------:
>   1 | 23-11 00 00       | 23-11 11 00       |       2
>   2 | 23-11 11 00       | 23-11 11 11       |       3
>   3 | 23-11 11 11       | 23-11 11 11 11    |       4
>   4 | 23-11 11 11 11    | 23-11 11 11 11 11 |       5
>   5 | 23-11 11 11 11 11 | 23-11 11 11 11 13 |       6
>   6 | 23-11 11 11 11 13 | 23-11 11 11 13    |       7
>   7 | 23-11 11 11 13    | 23-11 11 11 15    |       8
>   8 | 23-11 11 11 15    | 23-11 11 11 17    |       9
>   9 | 23-11 11 11 17    | 23-11 11 11 19    |      10
>  10 | 23-11 11 11 19    | 23-11 11 11 21    |      11
>  11 | 23-11 11 11 21    | 23-11 11 13       |      12
>  12 | 23-11 11 13       | 23-11 11 13 11    |      13
>  13 | 23-11 11 13 11    | 23-11 13 00       |      14
>  14 | 23-11 13 00       | 23-11 13 11       |      15
>  15 | 23-11 13 11       | 23-11 13 11 11    |      16
>  16 | 23-11 13 11 11    | 23-11 13 11 13    |      17
>  17 | 23-11 13 11 13    | 23-11 13 11 15    |      18
>  18 | 23-11 13 11 15    | 23-11 13 11 17    |      19
>  19 | 23-11 13 11 17    | 23-11 13 11 17 11 |      20
>  20 | 23-11 13 11 17 11 | 23-11 13 11 17 13 |      21
>  21 | 23-11 13 11 17 13 | 23-11 13 11 19    |      22
>  22 | 23-11 13 11 19    | 23-11 13 11 21    |      23
>  23 | 23-11 13 11 21    | 23-11 13 11 21 11 |      24
>  24 | 23-11 13 11 21 11 | 23-11 13 11 23    |      25
>  25 | 23-11 13 11 23    | 23-11 13 11 25    |      26
>  26 | 23-11 13 11 25    | 23-11 13 11 25 11 |      27
>  27 | 23-11 13 11 25 11 | 23-11 13 11 25 13 |      28
>  28 | 23-11 13 11 25 13 | 23-11 13 11 27    |      29
>  29 | 23-11 13 11 27    | 23-11 15 00       |      30
>  30 | 23-11 15 00       | 23-11 15 11       |      31
>  31 | 23-11 15 11       | 23-11 15 11 11    |      32
>  32 | 23-11 15 11 11    | 23-11 15 11 13    |      33
>  33 | 23-11 15 11 13    | 23-11 15 11 15    |      34
>  34 | 23-11 15 11 15    | 23-11 15 11 17    |      35
>  35 | 23-11 15 11 17    | 23-11 15 11 19    |      36
>  36 | 23-11 15 11 19    | 23-11 15 11 21    |      37
>  37 | 23-11 15 11 21    | 23-11 15 11 23    |      38
>  38 | 23-11 15 11 23    | 23-11 15 11 25    |      39
>  39 | 23-11 15 11 25    | 23-11 15 13       |      40
>  40 | 23-11 15 13       | 23-11 15 13 11    |      41
>  41 | 23-11 15 13 11    | 23-11 15 13 13    |      42
>  42 | 23-11 15 13 13    | 23-11 15 13 15    |      43
>  43 | 23-11 15 13 15    | 23-11 15 13 17    |      44
>  44 | 23-11 15 13 17    | 23-11 15 13 19    |      45
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d89e0ec9ca0a3cfb7ea5e861c05d1bfb)*